# Tracking users when they have cookie disabled?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

What is the best way to track users on our Asp.net websites if they have there cookie disabled.

I heard about Flash cookies but could not find a good resource to access the flesh cookies using Asp.Net or JavaScript.

Does anyone know a better method?

Comment: possible typo: it's "Flash" cookie, see http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/04/flash-cookies-explained/

Comment: @Hans: That link explains flash cookies but is there a way to access it using .Net or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search turned up this: http://www.nuff-respec.com/technology/cross-browser-cookies-with-flash, with a flash file that is accessed through js. I haven't tried this.

I think it's not possible to use Flash-cookies without flash.

There's also html5 local storage: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Comment: Html5 is a good option but unfortunately a large percentage of users are still using IE6 :(

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward (and time-honoroed) method is to attach a session code to every internal link on your web site, e.g.

`http://www.mysite.aspx/page.aspx?id=xxxx-yyyy-zzzz`

Since you're using asp.net, using `POST` for navigation is easy enough already, so the code  can be buried in a hidden form field that you include as part of the page template.

But really, why worry? If someone has disabled cookies it's because they don't want their session tracked. Trying to find clever ways to violate the wishes of your users won't make them like you.